# Git server-side hook - committer name

Tags: git

On a Git server 1.8.1.4 with Gitlab 7.7.2 in the server-side hook file pre-receive (ruby) I can get the name of the user from the server database by the push commit into the server via SSH:

```
$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME['name']
```

I'd like to check the this user's name with the name of the committer.
I have tried to user the variable $GIT_COMMITTER_NAME, but I got the 'nil' value.

How to get the committer name set before the push by the client's command?

```
git config user.name "Joe Doe"
```

The same question for the email address ('user.email').

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean with _check the **this user's name** with the name of the committer_?

Comment: Something like if $GIT_AUTHOR_NAME['name'] != $GIT_COMMITTER_NAME['name'] exit 1

Comment: You want to compare if the commiter name equals the author name? May I ask why?

Comment: Let's say to avoid mess in commits. But of course the committer's name can have a different usage as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# pre-receive

refs = ARGF.read
key_id  = ENV['GL_ID']
...
# get the user
user = GitlabNet.new.discover(key_id)
author_name = user['name']

committer_name = `git show --pretty=oneline --pretty=format:%an #{newrev} | head -n1`.strip

if author_name != committer_name
    print "Name of the committer must be '" + author_name + "' but found '" + committer_name + "'.\n"
    exit 1
end
...
```

The `newrev` is SHA of the current commit, the value is taken from `refs`.

Comment: Great command! The 'oneline' pretty option does not help much in my case so I skipped it.